# How to find files on Linux with a name shorter than n characters?

Tags: linux, find

How can I find files on Linux that have a filename shorter than n characters?

For example, to have something to work with, I am looking recursively for all filenames within `/home/myuser` that are less than 5 characters long (so, a file with name `foo` should be found, but with name `barbaz` not because its name is longer than 4 characters) - how can I do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-name` option of `find` operates on the file name without the path. You can't say "shorter than" in a pattern, but you can say "longer than" and negate:

```
find . -not -name '?????*'
```

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping for a solution that takes an actual number, but this can easily be simulated by a bash script with a loop to write the according number of `?`.

Comment: @choroba You're right, you can't specify "shorter than" in find but you can say shorter than if you use regular expressions in grep. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Please try out this

```
find . -type f -exec basename {} \; | awk '{ if(length($0) < n) print $0 }'
```

where 'n' is no. of characters

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by piping the output of the find command into grep using extended regular expressions with the -E switch, viz:

`find -type f -exec basename {} \; | grep -E '^.{,4}$`'

In the grep part, the ^ means the first character position, the . means any character, the {,4} means 4 or less of the preceding character (which now means 4 or less of any character) and the $ means the last character position.

The command grep with the -E switch replaces what we used to know as egrep, which has now been been discontinued.